# Python Loop to generate random binary matrix of -1 or 1

Tags: python, numpy, while-loop

Instead of the typical binary 0 or 1, or two consecutive numbers, I need to create a loop which will generate three random -1s and 1s, 100 times. My code so far looks like:

```
new = []
i =1 
while i <= 100:
    random = np.random.randint(low=-1, high=1, size=(1,3))
    new.append(random)
    i += 1
print(new.append(random))
```

Though this just returns `None` and even if it was working, would return 0s as well which is not wanted.

Comment: Did you try to `print(new)`? Here you're just printing the function return value of another `.append()` call, which will be `None`

Answer (score 4):

No need to bother importing numpy - it may be easier to just use `random.choices()` (from the standard library) to generate three random choices from `[-1, 1]`, and do it 100 times.

```
import random

new = [random.choices([-1, 1], k=3) for _ in range(100)]
# [[1, 1, -1], 
#  [1, 1, 1], 
#  [1, 1, -1], 
#  [-1, -1, -1], 
#  ...
#  [1, -1, 1]]
```

If you're doing this inside a function, with the intent for that function to produce `new` for outside use, then don't forget to do `return new` at the end of the function.